# _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "0 1 2"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have a listBox in tkinter and 2 buttons. One of them delete the selected items in ListBox. If I select every items and y try delete them I get the follow error:

_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "0 1 2": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number

I don't find how I can to solve it.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Listas en tkinter")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=4)

def AgregarItem(event):
    # Obtener elementos del listbox
    elementos = lstProductos.get(0, tk.END)
    # Combprobar si nuevo elemento existe en listbox
    if item.get() in elementos:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(message="El elemento ya existe en la lista",
                               title="Error")
    else:
        lstProductos.insert(tk.END, item.get())
    
    txtProducto.delete(0, "end")

def EliminarItem(event):
    elementos = lstProductos.get(0, tk.END)
    if elementos != (): 
        lstProductos.delete(lstProductos.curselection())

# Titulo
lblTitulo = ttk.Label(root, text="Lista de la compra")
lblTitulo.configure(font=("Arial", 24, 'bold'))
lblTitulo.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)

# Lista
lstProductos = tk.Listbox(root)
lstProductos.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=3, pady=5)
lstProductos.configure(selectmode="multiple")

# Scrollbar de la lista
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=lstProductos.yview)
scrollbar.grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=3, sticky=tk.NS, pady=5)
lstProductos['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Etiqueta con instrucciones
lblInstrucciones = ttk.Label(root, text="Agregar: Introduce el nombre\ndel producto y pulsa Agregar\n\nEliminar: Selecciona producto\ny pulsa Eliminar")
lblInstrucciones.grid(column=2, row=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# Cuadro de texto
item=tk.StringVar()
txtProducto = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=item)
txtProducto.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)


# Boton agregar 
botAgregar = tk.Button(root, text="Agregar item" )
botAgregar.grid(column=2, row=3)
botAgregar.bind('<Button-1>', AgregarItem)

# Boton eliminar
botEliminar = tk.Button(root, text="Eliminar item" )
botEliminar.grid(column=3, row=3)
botEliminar.bind('<Button-1>', EliminarItem)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to delete a set of items in a listbox is by getting the list of selected indexes and then looping through it and then individually deleting them.

But there is a problem in that, if you delete the first selected index then you will notice the index positions of other elements *below the deleted item* now change too and hence deleting will not be proper. So you will have to delete from the bottom so the previous items do not get reindexed after deletion:

```
def EliminarItem(event):
    elementos = lstProductos.get(0, tk.END)
    items = lstProductos.curselection()

    if elementos: # Same as `if elemntos != ()`
        for i in items[::-1]: # items[::-1] will reverse the list
            lstProductos.delete(i)
```

---

Note that you are using `bind` with the buttons, which is absolutely unnecessary. You should really be using `command` option of button, which will trigger the function when button is pressed.

```
# Boton agregar 
botAgregar = tk.Button(root, text="Agregar item", command=AgregarItem)
botAgregar.grid(column=2, row=3)
```

... and don't forget to remove `event` as a parameter in the functions as you are no longer passing it in.